# JSON.NET - Write a nested list with two sets of brackets

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I have a Windows Forms .NET application and I am writing JSON formatted text to a text file using the Newtonsoft JSON.NET library. I want to write two sets of brackets to denote that `points` is a list of lists even though it only contains one list (shown below).

```
{
    "rallyPoints:" {
        "points": [
            [
                0.0,
                1.0,
                2.0
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

void exampleFunction()
{
    string filePath = @"path/to/file.json";
    List<List<double>> rallyPoints = new List<List<double>>();
    List<double> singleRallyPoint = new List<double>
    {
        0.0, 1.0, 2.0
    };
    rallyPoints.Add(singleRallyPoint);

    JObject mainObject = new JObject(
        new JProperty("rallyPoints", new JObject(
        new JProperty("points", rallyPoints)
        ))
    );

    using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(filePath))
    using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(file))
    {
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        mainObject.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

My code writes to the text file as shown below. Notice that the `points` field only has one set of brackets rather than two sets so it is not clear that this is a list of lists.

```
{
    "rallyPoints:" {
        "points": [
            0.0,
            1.0,
            2.0
        ]
    }
}
```

I am not sure if what I am trying to accomplish is a proper JSON format. Maybe it's the case that with JSON a list of lists containing only a single list as an element is formatted as a list. I haven't been able to verify that online thus far. Even if what I am attempting is not proper JSON I would still like to know if there is a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is proper JSON, it's an array of arrays. Why not just use a proper object model. Eg `class YourClass { RallyPoints rallyPoints }` `class RallyPoints { List<List<double>> points }` and then serialize that? Why mess around manually writing the JSON?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the `List<List<double>>` to `JArray` should solve the issue.

```cs
JArray.FromObject(rallyPoints)
```

```cs
JObject mainObject = new JObject(
    new JProperty("rallyPoints", 
        new JObject(
            new JProperty("points", JArray.FromObject(rallyPoints))
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ocotI)

Comment: No problem, good to see it helps. The answers from Charlie and Serge are good and easier solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to use an anonymous type

```
void exampleFunction()
{
    string filePath = @"path/to/file.json";

    var result = new
    {
        rallyPoinst = new
        {
            points = new List<List<double>> {
                     new List<double> {
                        0.0, 1.0, 2.0
                     }}
        }
    };

    var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
}
```